# Yajra DataTable Search-box and pagination not working with Laravel 5.4 on digital ocean online

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

I'm using Laravel 5.4 with Yajra DataTable 8.0, on localhost everything working well and DataTable all ok. However, When I upload my files on "digital ocean" online server, Datatable working but for Pagination not working completely. It shows all records (6420 records) per each slide of pagination. On localhost it shows 10 records per page as normal, but online it shows all records in each slide of pagination.

Another problem which is the search box, which not working at all. It shows processing in every typing for any text inside it. However, no results after typing anything inside it.

Here in my header:

```
<head>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>

</head>
```

and this is the table:

```
<table id="student_table" class="this_testing table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>primary_number</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

This is my JS:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.this_testing').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "lead/testing"

            },
            columns: [
                {"data": "id", "name": "id"},
                {"data": "name", "name": "name"}
            ],
            // bSort: true,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            ]
        });

    });

</script>
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('lead/testing', 'LeadController@testing');
Route::get('lead/testings', 'LeadController@testings');
```

Lastly by Controller to get the Data:

```
public function testings()
{
    return view('testing');
}

public function testing()
{
    $allClients = Status::select('id','name');
    return DataTables::of($allClients)->make(true);
}
```

There is no any Ajax error in Network or Inspect, I got the data correct from Controller, but my problem in showing the DataTable on "digital ocean" server, it keep showing all response records (6320 records) in each slide of pagination, which make the page too long and the pagination need a time to load. I want to make it work as normal, 10 records per page, is there any conflict or library missed.

Another problem, Search box showing processing in every typing, but not working and no results affected.

Any help please,
I'm using Laravel 5.4 and DataTable ^8.0 on Digital Ocean Server

Comment: Pagination need GET route to work and can you please update searching functionality

Comment: Thanks for your response, I update my question and add the route, where I already used GET in route to get the data. Qs, what u mean by update searching functionality?

Comment: Okay but where is the searching form ? and which one is your searching method i don't see any parameter passed

Comment: I'm using Yajra Datatable, where the search box came build in the dependency.